# Preparing Likert Data for CFA

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, likert, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I've been running a CFA on Likert scale data that averages the responses for each item, and I've been thinking that if I could possibly run the analysis without averaging the responses, it might improve the model and allow the possibility of using the DWLS estimator.

When preparing Likert survey data for a CFA, can the respondents' entries be listed individually? This means there will be multiple scores recorded for each item and I'm unsure how this will work in R.

If it will work, I'll go back to my data source and try to get the respondents' individual entries. (I'm learning this on my own so I apologize in advance if this seems like a basic question.)

Comment: I'm not sure from your description, but if you have duplicate entries in the sense of multiple measurements on an individual, then you should take some consideration toward having random effects in your model.

Comment: It was my mistake for not effectively wording the question. What I meant was, for example, if there are 25 respondents it will result in 25 scores for each item. Can we record each score individually and run the CFA on this data, or do we need to average the 25 scores for each question in order to run it?

Comment: If each of *N* subjects provides a response to each of *I* items, there should be one subject per row and one variable (scale item) per column: an *N*-by-*I* data matrix. You syntax will refer to the variable names: https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/